# Converting MM:DD:YYYY hh:mm:ss to DD:MM:YYYY hh:mm:ss in excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert the timestamp data in Microsoft excel where the timestamp is coming as
**MM:DD:YYYY hh:mm:ss (12/25/2016 12:00:55 AM)**.
this Formet doesnt support in excel and i wanted to change it to 
 **DD:MM:YYYY hh:mm:ss (25/12/2016 12:00:55 AM)**
i have seached so many times but all i get is *DD:MM:YYYY to MM:DD:YYYY* which is not the case.

Comment: Is the cell formatted as text? If yes then you can use left() and mid()

Comment: No it is set as general , but if i set it as text as well how would i convert it as DD:MM:YYYY

Comment: How are dates arriving in Excel?  Do you type them in or are they imported from another file (and which file type - csv?)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook
it is coming from the other data source

Comment: It would be easier to import as a datetime rather than text.

Answer (score 2):

Either add a column with `=MID(B2,4,3) & LEFT(B2,2) & RIGHT(B2,17)` where B2 is replaced with your date value cell reference (The formula only works if all dates are in that 22 character format you used as an example).

or

write a macro to amend the values in that column.

Comment: Hi Jason,
the date format i mentioned has general format , do i have to change it to any other format before applying your formula ,or should i directly use it in new column??

Comment: The formula can only be used in a new column. You'll end up with two columns, the before conversion value and the after. If you want it as a date value rather than text you can use `=DATEVALUE(MID(B2,4,3) & LEFT(B2,2) & MID(B2,6,5)) + TIMEVALUE( RIGHT(B2,12))`

Comment: Thanks For your Answer but... 

I tried your formula **=MID(B2,4,3) & LEFT(B2,2) & RIGHT(B2,17)** which works but for some date its showing stranger results like.. 
input is this ---> 12/21/2016 1:27:00 PM 
Out is this ---> 21/121/2016 1:27:00 PM (121 which should not be coming)
there are few other results as well which are not coming as expected.

Comment: It's all about counting characters. Try '=DATEVALUE(MID(B2,4,3) & LEFT(B2,2) & MID(B2,6,5)) + TIMEVALUE( RIGHT(B2,11))' instead. You can then format the column in whatever date format you want as it will be a datetime value rather than text.